# Какие существуют причины возникновения LazyInitializationException?

Tags: java, spring

Ссылка к моему [проекту](https://github.com/Dimassss/Spring)
Вопрос: Какие существуют причины возникновения этой ошибки? Также что может вызывать в моем проекте?
Дополнительно: Для уточнений каких либо вопросов пишите в комментариях.
Для того чтоб получить такую ошибку вы должны попробовать зарегистрироваться. После этого вы получить вот такую ошибку:

```
01-Jun-2017 21:06:22.420 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
01-Jun-2017 21:06:26.711 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
01-Jun-2017 21:06:57.392 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
01-Jun-2017 21:07:06.307 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
01-Jun-2017 21:08:05.596 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher'
01-Jun-2017 21:10:08.187 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher'
01-Jun-2017 21:10:32.364 SEVERE [http-nio-8086-exec-3] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session] with root cause
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:165)
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:286)
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
at net.module4.spring.model.Role_$$_jvst51d_0.hashCode(Role_$$_jvst51d_0.java)
at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:338)
at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:611)
at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:219)
at net.module4.spring.service.UserServiceImpl.save(UserServiceImpl.java:31)
at net.module4.spring.service.UserServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$243a6c47.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
at net.module4.spring.service.UserServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$937f47d0.save(<generated>)
at net.module4.spring.controller.Controller.registration(Controller.java:50)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:120)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:745)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1437)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

Используй у roleDao метод, возвращающий объект `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository#findOne(ID)`

Потому что getOne возвращает ссылку, а тебе нужен объект для вычисления hashCode( вставка в коллекцию HashSet)

И дальше обрати внимание на сохранение вложенных коллекций.

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "user_roles",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
)
private Set<Role> roles;
```

У аннотации @ManyToMany можно задать fetch(стратегия на получение данных) и cascade(стратегия на модификацию). 
Например так :

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

Еще советую взглянуть на параметры @JoinColumn (флаги на update, insert), потому что по умолчанию они не всегда подходят.

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы избежать **LazyInitializationException**  используйте **DTO** (Data transfer object). Здесь  пример кода использования **DTO** (вопросы различаются, но пример подходит) [Ограничение длины пароля в Spring Security](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777791/%D0%9E%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2-spring-security/785009#785009)

Рассмотрим один из вариантов:

```
@Entity
class Owner{
    ...

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Set<Car> cars;
    ...
}
```

У вас есть эндпоинт, который запрашивает Owner по id:

1. Вы достаете из базы **owner**. Теперь у объекта **owner** поле **cars** ссылается на объект **`PersistentSet<Car>`**, который **инициализируется(заполняется объектами), только при обращении к его методам**. Для этого **PersistentSet держит hibernate сессию**, при помощи который был получен объект **owner**.
2. Вы никаким образом не взаимодействовали с полем  **cars**,  а просто сразу вернули объект **Owner** из метода контроллера. Дальше **Spring** начинает процесс сериализации **owner** в  **json**. Сериализатор обращается к полю **cars**, пытается получить итератор, но это **PersistentSet**, перед тем как вернуть итератор, он пытается проинициализироваться(заполниться объектами), а **hibernate сессия уже закрыта**, вот и **возникает LazyInitializationException**.

Вот как выглядит второй шаг при использовании DTO:

- после получения **owner** из базы, в контроллере вы конвертите  **Owner -> OwnerDTO**,  при этом поле  cars из **`PersistentSet<Car>` -> например в `HashSet<CarDTO>`**. Теперь, когда вы возвращаете из контроллера **OwnerDTO, ни он сам, ни его поля не держат hibernate сессию**, поэтому **LazyInitializationException не возникнет**.