# Ограничение длины пароля в Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, password

Делаю регистрацию юзера. Длина пароля должна быть от 6 до 16 символов. Сначала думал воспользоваться аннотацией  `@Size(min = 6, max = 16)` в энтити, но потом выяснил, что после шифрования пароля `BCryptPasswordEncoder` именно зашифрованную часть проверяет `@Size`, а это 60 символов. Как мне реализовать эту функцию? Думал сделать через сервис, но как по мне это хардкод, уверен есть решение лучше.

SellerController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class SellerController {

  @Autowired
  SellerServiceImpl sellerService;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/seller-registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ResponseEntity<String> sellerRegistration(@Valid @RequestBody Seller newSeller) {
    Seller seller = sellerService.save(newSeller);
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).build();
  }
}
```

Seller:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Seller {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "username", unique = true)
  @NotNull(message = "username can not be null.")
  private String username;

  @Column(name = "password")
  @NotNull(message = "password can not be null.")
  //@Size(min = 6, max = 15)
  private String password;

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
  private Set<Role> roles;

  @Column(name = "email", unique = true)
  @NotNull(message = "email can not be null.")
  @Email
  private String email;
```

SellerServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class SellerServiceImpl {

  @Autowired
  SellerRepository sellerRepository;

  @Autowired
  RoleRepository roleRepository;

  @Autowired
  PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

  public SellerServiceImpl() {
  }

  public SellerServiceImpl(SellerRepository sellerRepository, RoleRepository roleRepository,
      PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
    this.sellerRepository = sellerRepository;
    this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
    this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
  }

  public Seller save(Seller seller) {
    seller.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(seller.getPassword()));
    Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
    roles.add(roleRepository.findOne(2L));
    seller.setRoles(roles);
    return sellerRepository.save(seller);
  }
}
```

Comment: Валидацией пароля должна заниматься клиентская часть

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте использовать DTO(Data transfer object). DTO помогает избежать проблем с сериализацией. Также это поможет избежать LazyInitializationException. Подробнее прочитать можно здесь
 [Наглядный пример различия DTO, POCO (POJO) и Value Object](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/456623/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F-dto-poco-pojo-%D0%B8-value-object).

```
public class SellerDTO{
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    @Size(min = 6, max = 16)
    private String password;
    private Set<RoleDTO> roles;
    private String email;
    ...
}

@Component
public class SelletDtoConverter{
    public SellerDTO toDTO(Seller seller){
        ...
    }

    public Seller fromDTO(SellerDTO sellerDTO){
        ...
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class SellerController {

    @Autowired
    SellerServiceImpl sellerService;
    @Autowired
    private SellerDtoConverter dtoConverter; 

    @RequestMapping(value = "/seller-registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> sellerRegistration(@Valid @RequestBody SellerDTO newSellerDTO) {
    Seller newSeller = dtoConverter.fromDTO(newSellerDTO);
    Seller seller = sellerService.save(newSeller);
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Лично я делал валидацию пароля средствами [Validator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Validator.html).
То есть создавал реализацию интерфейса, в методе писал регулярку для пароля.

А затем использовал метод в контроллере.